# Is spring boot required with Firebase for Android?

Tags: android, spring, firebase, spring-boot

I'm really sorry if this is not the right place to ask such question, please refer me where I can ask if this is not.

I'm developing an Android application and using Firebase as backend to store data. I'm new to both Firebase and Springboot. I've been told to learn to create some basic APIs in SpringBoot but I have been question why I would need to.

From what I got to know, Firebase already provides an API for querying data that I might need to transfer. What is the use of SpringBoot? I've read it provides "easy-deployable" application and handles Unit and Integration Testing.

If I use SpringBoot on top of Firebase, isn't it redundant? Are there additional advantages that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SpringBoot is completely **independent** of Firebase.

Firebase is basically a service which is provided by Google so that the developer doesn't need to do server-side coding.

SpringBoot is a framework which is generally used for the development of the server-side application.

By using firebase you need to pay google for data storage and API usage stuff. If we compare using firebase & spring-boot application in terms of costing taking same amount of data storage, the amount you need to pay for firebase is a lot more. Though this amount is justified, as you don't need to write even a single line of code for server-end and all the server connections, data storage and security is maintained by firebase.

You can learn more about firebase on it's official website - https://firebase.google.com/

If you are starting, I would recommend you to learn and use SpringBoot rather than firebase. But if your application demands a real-time database, you must go for firebase to take care of that feature.

Here is an article for your reference [Reasons Not To Use Firebase](https://crisp.chat/blog/why-you-should-never-use-firebase-realtime-database/)

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot is not required to use Firebase SDKs on Android. The Firebase SDKs operate completely independently of any backend you control.

If you want to provide Spring Boot backend for your Android app, that's completely up to you.  Or whatever backend you want.  The Firebase client SDKs don't care.